# Compras/Restauro dentro da app em Android

Tags: android, android-billing

Estou a realizar uma app que terá compras in app (esconder publicidade e novas funcionalidades), no entanto estou com algumas duvidas.
Todo o processo de compra já esta a funcionar, bem esconder a publicidade e as novas funcionalidades estarem disponíveis ao utilizador no entanto tenho dois duvidas.

1. Imaginamos que o utilizador formata o telemóvel(ou muda de tlm), saca novamente a minha app, mas está terá ainda a publicidade, o utilizador para obter a app completa sem voltar a pagar, basta realizar o processo de compra novamente (e a Google sabe que ele ja comprou e não cobra nada) ou é preciso implementar um botão na app para permitir fazer o restauro?
2. O utilizador faz a compra in app, mas depois quer recuperar o seu dinheiro (p.e. arrependimento ou não gostou, etc). Neste caso, como é que o utilizador obtém o seu dinheiro? Pergunto isto, porque já li algures que em compras in app o utilizador não consegue recuperar o seu dinheiro, isto é verdade?

Comment: Está usando o `Google Play In-app Billing`?

Comment: Sim @Wakim, estou a usar essa biblioteca da Google

Comment: Todas as compras feitas são associadas ao usuário, não ao dispositivo. Você só precisa consultar as compras feitas em seu app para saber se o usuário já comprou anteriormente. Com relação ao `refund`, ele pode ser feito e tem que ser feito manualmente por você.

Comment: Como consigo "consultar as compras feitas em seu app para saber se o usuário já comprou anteriormente"?
Em relacao ao **refund**, encontrei que em purchase in app os refund sao manuais entre o utilizador e o comerciante

Comment: No item 2 do `Purchasing Items` (http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#purchase) ele diz que pode fazer a consulta (tem até cache local, o que permite fazer a consulta mais frequentemente).

Comment: Não sei quem suspendeu esta thread, mas isto tem a haver com programação.
Obrigado pelas respostas até ao momento

Comment: Ok, vou reabrir a pergunta com base no [penúltimo item desta meta-pergunta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264/). CC @Wakim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As compras feitas pelo **Google Play in-app Billing v3** são sempre atreladas a conta do usuário no *Google Play*, não importando se ele removeu seu app, formatou o dispositivo, comprou outro. Desde que tudo aconteça com a mesma conta<sup>1</sup>.

1. Sempre que iniciar o app, você pode consultar usando o `getPurchases` (O *Google Play Services* ainda faz cache das compras, o que não onera tanto nesse caso) se o usuário já pagou pela remoção de ads ou liberação de recursos, exemplo de código<sup>2</sup>:

   ```
   Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, getPackageName(), "inapp", null);

   int response = ownedItems.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");

   if (response == 0) {
       ArrayList<String> ownedSkus = ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_ITEM_LIST");
       ArrayList<String>  purchaseDataList = ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA_LIST");
       ArrayList<String>  signatureList = ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE");

       String continuationToken = ownedItems.getString("INAPP_CONTINUATION_TOKEN");

       for (int i = 0; i < purchaseDataList.size(); ++i) {
           String purchaseData = purchaseDataList.get(i);
           String signature = signatureList.get(i);
           String sku = ownedSkus.get(i);

           JSONObject purchaseJSON = new JSONObject(purchaseData);

           // Você também pode verificar o purchaseState
           // (0 para purchased, 1 para canceled e 2 para refunded)
           int purchaseState = purchaseJSON.getInt("purchaseState");

           if(purchaseState == 0) {
               // Faça algo com a informação dessa compra
               // Desabilitar ADS, liberar funcionalidades ou
               // atualizar um SharedPreferences para não
               // precisar consultar denovo.
           }
       }

       // se continuationToken != null, chame getPurchases denovo 
       // e passe o token para obter mais items
       // O limite que o Google Play retorna é de 700 itens
   }
   ```
2. Para fazer o reembolso de uma compra, o usuário deverá lhe contactar por e-mail ou outro meio de comunicação e solicitar o cancelamento. O cancelamento deve ser feito manualmente por você no *Google Wallet Merchant*.

   É possível detectar reembolsos usando o código de estado da compra no método `getPurchases`, ao realizar o reembolso de um item que foi comprado, o campo `purchaseState` virá com valor **2**<sup>3</sup> (salvo algum delay de comunicação), sendo feito um tratamento para que a remoção de Ads ou liberação de funcionalidades volte ao estado anterior.

### Referências:

1. http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#purchase e http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#consume (Parágrafo sobre "Non-consumable Items")
2. Código de exemplo do `getPurchases` foi tirado de http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html.
3. Tabelas 4 e 5 com o campos disponíveis nos métodos usados: http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta..
Tive a ler e para testar isto antes da publicação, necessito de enviar o apk para a store (alpha) e user utilizadores de testes para que nao seja cobrado nenhum valor.
Só não percebo é se estes utilizadores de teste tem de ter um cartão de credito associado ou não, consegues responder a isto?

Comment: @Kiotto, existem duas modalidades: As `Test Purchase's` onde não gera nenhum encargo, mas você precisa cria-las no console para não serem cobrados. E o teste "Real", com um produto de verdade e que irá gerar uma cobrança mesmo para uma conta de teste. Com relação ao cartão, não deve ser necessário pois o `Google Play` tem outros métodos de pagamento ( https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2651410?hl=en) e ( https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#testing-purchases).

Comment: Agora em relação as `Testing Purchases`, eu acredito que não precisa de nenhum método de pagamento, **não tenho certeza**, é preciso testar antes.

Comment: Para realizar o pagamento, tive de meter um numero de CC válido, mas depois o dinheiro não é retirado.
Mas depois da compra feita e usado o código, é devolvido que ainda não fiz compras

Comment: @Kiotto, a compra aparece no `Google Wallet Merchant` como concluída? O `getPackageName` retorna o mesmo cadastrado no `Google Play`?

Comment: No Google Wallet Merchant aparece com a bola amarela, o getPackgageName devolva o nome do pacote que declarei no manifest.
Neste método Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, getPackageName(), "inapp", null); o getPackName() é o nome do pacote ou o nome do sku declarado no google play developer?

Comment: @Kiotto, esse tem que ser o `packageName` mesmo.

Comment: Então é o correto :(

Comment: @Kiotto, pelo que vi, o círculo amarelo diz que a transação está pendente. Vi essa informação aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23549953/google-transaction-canceled.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17407/discussion-between-kiotto-and-wakim).

Comment: Vou esperar que fique verde, mas se isto começar a funcionar após ficar verde não faz sentido porque este processo demora em média 7 horas. E o utilizador quando compra fica logo disponível, o método getPurchases devia devolver logo isso.

Comment: O Estado nao passa a verde, como é um teste o estado nao deve mudar...

Comment: Resolvido, finalmente..
O problema é que no acto da compra, estava a usar o metodo  mHelper.consumeAsync, e não devo usar.
Retirei e já faço compras e consigo saber se o user comprou ou não.
Questão, onde viste que o código do result para o refund é 2?

Comment: Tabela 4: http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html, vou esclarecer melhor isso na resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Fiz um teste, ou seja fiz uma compra in app, mas com o codigo de cima, ele devolve que nao ha produtos comprados.
Tenho este código:

```
     mServiceConn = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            mService = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            mService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);

            try {
                Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, getPackageName(), "inapp", null);

                int response = ownedItems.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");

                if (response == 0) {

                    ArrayList<String> ownedSkus = ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_ITEM_LIST");
                    ArrayList<String> purchaseDataList = ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA_LIST");
                    ArrayList<String> signatureList = ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE");
                    String continuationToken = ownedItems.getString("INAPP_CONTINUATION_TOKEN");

                    if (purchaseDataList.size() > 0) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < purchaseDataList.size(); ++i) {
                            String purchaseData = purchaseDataList.get(i);
                            String signature = signatureList.get(i);
                            String sku = ownedSkus.get(i);

                            Utils.showPopUp(PreferencesActivity.this, "Info", "purchaseData: " + purchaseData + "\nsignature: " + signature + "\nsku: " + sku, false);

                            //TODO REVER
                            shared.setPurchaseInApp(true);
                        }
                    } else {
                        //TODO REVER
                        Utils.showPopUp(PreferencesActivity.this, "Info", "Não efectou compras", false);
                        shared.setPurchaseInApp(false);
                        initPurchaseInApp();
                    }
                }
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };

    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
    serviceIntent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
    bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```